# jquery mobile ui grid 3 colum

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

hello i need a 3 colums layout in jquery mobile.
i load my json file and i need to put the first obj in ui-block-a the second obj in ui-block-b the third obj in ui-block-c the fourth obj in ui-block-a and so on....
i can make with two colums checking if is odd or even, this is my code:

```
for (var i in data.cappelli) {
        if( i%2 == 0)output+="<div class=\"ui-block-a\">" + data.cappelli[i].id + " " + data.cappelli[i].nome + "</div>";
        else output+="<div class=\"ui-block-b\">" + data.cappelli[i].id + " " + data.cappelli[i].nome + "</div>";
}
```

can someone help me to achieve that in 3 column??

Ty very much

Answer (score 1):

```
grids = ['a','b','c'];
for (var i in data.cappelli) {
    output+="<div class=\"ui-block-" + grids[i%3] + "\">" + data.cappelli[i].id + " " + data.cappelli[i].nome + "</div>";
}
```